# How to get Current page path in dialog in CQ5

Tags: javascript, java, aem

**How to get Current page path in dialog in CQ5**

```
options="$PATH./bin/QuickAccessBarServlet/getContactBarLabels.json"

@SlingServlet(
        extensions = { "json" },
        metatype=true,
        methods = { "GET" }, 
        paths={"/bin/QuickAccessBarServlet"}, 
        selectors = QuickAccessBarServlet.SELECTOR_GET_CONTACT_BAR_LABELS)
```

Comment: I don't know how to pass the page path to be available in the request.

Answer (score 0):

For calling a path based servlet to return JSON object, you dont need to path of current page.

Look at this - `/libs/mcm/components/cta-form/start/dialog/items/tabs/items/second/items/actiontype` for reference. You can directly specify the servlet path in the options field.

Comment: In the dialog in option field just path options="/bin/QuickAccessBarServlet/getContactBarLabels. But then in the servlet in request I can't get currentpage path

Comment: i still can't get the currentPage path in the servlet :( any ideas?

Comment: A path based servlet will never have currentPage.

Comment: What is the use case, why do you need currentPage or any if the default object in path based servlet.

Comment: currentPage = pageManager.getContainingPage(request.getResource());

Comment: i shoud post the current page with request

Comment: maybe with   <listeners
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        selectionchanged

Comment: The resource in your case is an instance of nonexistingresource type in other words a virtual path which can not have a page associated to it. You may try the listener approach, pass the page path as argument and resolve that path to resource and then page to get the page instance you need

Comment: i'm trying to pass it but no success, can you help me, please

Comment: <listeners
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        selectionchanged="function(box, value) {
                                             var dialog = this.findParentByType('dialog');
                                             var dialog = dlg.find('name', './externallink')[0];
                                             CQ.Ext.Ajax.request({url: '/bin/QuickAccessBarServlet1.json?value=' + value + & quot; & amp;path = & quot; + CQ.WCM.getPagePath(),;

Comment: You need to tell me the use case, a dialog field to be dependent on a content is usually not a good practice. Why do you need currentPage at all to populate dropdown options.

Comment: this dialog should be added in different pages, and i should know the exact page to get correct data in the servlet

Comment: Then dont use path based servlet, use servlet with resourceType `sling.servlet.resourceTypes = \[ "sling/unused" \]`
`sling.servlet.selectors = \[ "mycompdialog"\]`
`sling.servlet.extensions = \[ "json" \]`

In your listener above, get the current URI and append .mycompdialog.json and make the ajax call. This way you can get the currentPage. I haven't done something like (exploiting URI) this but logically this will work.

Comment: do you have any example of that?

Comment: What version of aem are you using?

Comment: Last qstn : classic ui or touch ui component?

Comment: i'm using classic ui

Comment: Look at the plugin described here - http://labs.6dglobal.com/blog/2014-04-07/cq-dialog-dynamically-generate-rootpath/

`CQ.HTTP.getPath();` you could pass it to your servlet as a parameter, no need to write resourcetype based servlet, you could do it with the existing path servlet. i.e In your listener above instead of using `CQ.WCM.getPagePath()` use `CQ.HTTP.getPath();`

Comment: String currentPagePath = new URI(request.getHeader("referer")).getPath(); i'm getting path like that. i find solution :)